# Combine Two Multidimensional Arrays in PHP With The Same ID

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add values from one array to another that are both potentially multidimensional when they have the same ID. Hard to explain so I added example.

arr1 => new structure, without full data

arr2 => old structure, with full data

Examples if you'd like to help out:

```
// arr1 (the correct structure/order, without the full data)
[{
    "id": "24",
    "children": [{
        "id": "21",
        "children": [{
            "id": "15"
        }]
    }]
}]



// arr2 (full data, not in any specific order, may be nested)
[{
    "id": "24",
    "name": " x",
    "time": "0",
    "status": "0"
}, {
    "id": "21",
    "children": [{
        "id": "15",
        "name": "x",
        "time": "0",
        "status": "0"
    }],
    "name": "x",
    "time": "0",
    "status": "0"
}]


// arr3 (desired output for this example)
[{
    "id": "24",
    "children": [{
        "id": "21",
        "children": [{
            "id": "15",
            "name": "x",
            "time": "0",
            "status": "0"
        }],
        "name": "x",
        "time": "0",
        "status": "0"
    }],
    "name": " x",
    "time": "0",
    "status": "0"
}]
```

I tried this:

```
    function merge($arr1, $arr2) {
        foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
            foreach($arr2 as $value2) {
                if($value['id'] === $value2['id']){
                    $arr1[$key]['name'] = $value2['name'];
                    $arr1[$key]['time'] = $value2['time'];
                    $arr1[$key]['status'] = $value2['status'];
                    if (is_array($value)) {
                        $arr1[$key]['children'] = merge($arr1, $arr2);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return $arr1;
    }
```

to combine them, but I can't figure out how to handle the nesting correctly. I have tried a lot of other things as well like using array_merge_recursive() but it doesn't work because I want to merge based on ID value. Any help on getting me on track would be awesome thanks.

Current output for example:

```
[{
    "id": "24",
    "children": [{
        "id": "21",
        "children": [{
            "id": "15"
        }]
    }],
    "name": " x",
    "time": "0",
    "status": "0"
}]
```

Desired output for example:

```
[{
    "id": "24",
    "children": [{
        "id": "21",
        "children": [{
            "id": "15",
            "name": "x",
            "time": "0",
            "status": "0"
        }],
        "name": "x",
        "time": "0",
        "status": "0"
    }],
    "name": " x",
    "time": "0",
    "status": "0"
}]
```

Comment: What is going wrong right now? Can you also show the _current_ output?

Comment: those json strings are not valid, btw.

Comment: Hey @Jeff I added smaller ones that work! I want to clarify that the structure is not exact and may be 20 levels deep, or may be 1 level, thanks!

Comment: @Jeff I also added current output example for the working json data. It copies anything not in a sub-array correctly, but does not work on any of the inner-arrays.

Comment: From your example I'm starting to understand better - you want the person with ID "21" from arr2 be move to become the child of "24", right?

Comment: correct, as an example, the arr1 will always be how I want it structured, and arr2 will be a different structure, with complete data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** How about this?

```
$detailsClean = [];

foreach($array2 as $item) {
    $detailsClean = removeDepth($item, $detailsClean);
}


foreach($array1 as $itemKey => $item) {
    $array1[$itemKey] = addDetails($item, $detailsClean);
}


function removeDepth($array, $result) {
    $id = $array['id'];
    if (!empty($array['children'])) {
        foreach($array['children'] as $child) {
            $result = removeDepth($child, $result);
        }
        unset($array['children']);
    }
    $result[$id] = $array;

    return $result;
}

function addDetails($array, $details) {
    $id = $array['id'];
    if (isset($details[$id])) {
        $array = array_merge($array, $details[$id]);
        if (!empty($array['children'])) {
            foreach($array['children'] as $childKey => $child) {
                $array['children'][$childKey] = addDetails($child, $details);
            }
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

$array1 is updated with the final result.

Here is an example with the data from your unedited post: http://phpio.net/s/7z09

Comment: yes children can have children which can have children, etc. which is why I am sure recursion is needed here. Your solution just returns a result with a single array with arr1 and then arr2 appended onto the end.

Comment: @JacobSussan Added a new example that first removes depth from all details (array2) and then loops trough array1 to add this details.

Comment: thanks you're a live saver, been trying to figure this out all day.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - I think I understand the problem now

From the example you gave, I realised the problem - your old array has all the data, but not the parent-child relationships, so you want to populate the new array (with the correct relationships) with the data form the old array. The problem here is that the merge function would have to fetch data from an arbitrary generation in the old array to populate the new array. This could mean a lot of looping.

So I think the solution is first to loop through the old data and flatten it - just have an associative array where the key is the "id" value. Then go through the new array and populate it from the flattened, "lookup" array. Does that make sense? In any case, you'd have two functions:

```
$lookUp = array();

//recursive function to flatten $arr2 into $lookUp array.
function indexOriginal($arr, &$lookUp) {
    foreach($arr as $value) {
        $lookUp[$value["id"]] = $value;
        if (isset($value['children'])) {
            unset($lookUp[$value["id"]]['children']);
            indexOriginal($value['children'], $lookUp);
        }
    }
}
indexOriginal($arr2, $lookUp);
```

Then you populate the new array:

```
function fillInNew($arr, $lookUp) {
    $return = array();
    foreach($arr as $value) {
        $newEntry = $lookUp[$value["id"]];
        if (isset($value['children'])) $newEntry['children'] = fillInNew($value['children'], $lookUp);
        $return[] = $newEntry;
    }
    return $return;
}
$newArr = fillInNew($arr1, $lookUp);
```

And $newArr should be what you're looking for

OLD USELESS STUFF FROM BEFORE:

This part of your code is weird to me:

```
if (is_array($value)) {
    $arr1[$key]['children'] = merge($arr1, $arr2);
}
```

Obviously I may be completely confused, but don't you just need to put this?

```
if (isset($value2['children'])) $arr1[$key]['children'] = array_merge($arr1[$key]['children'], $value2['children']);
```

EDIT: I added array_merge because I saw that the 'children' array in the incomplete version could also need merging.

EDIT 2: now I've noticed that children can have further children (makes sense, I guess), which is why you had the correct idea of using the function recursively. You just seem to have passed in the wrong arrays - you want to pass in $arr1[$key]['children'] (as the incomplete array) and $value2['children'] (as the complete array)

```
function merge($arr1, $arr2) {
    foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
        foreach($arr2 as $value2) {
            if($value['id'] === $value2['id']){
                $arr1[$key]['name'] = $value2['name'];
                $arr1[$key]['time'] = $value2['time'];
                $arr1[$key]['status'] = $value2['status'];
                if (isset($value2['children'])) $arr1[$key]['children'] = merge($arr1[$key]['children'], $value2['children']);
            }

        }
    }
    return $arr1;
}
```

Comment: right but this will just copy the children over, and since the children may be there in array1, but not array2, or vise versa, this will not work on levels besides the top one.

Comment: Just spotted that and edited the line. I think the issue with your initial code was the line if (is_array($value)), which is only checking in arr1, which might be incomplete, right? checking on $value2 seems to make more sense

Comment: This doesn't copy any data (name, time, status) from the levels after the first one.

Comment: Did you see the second edit? Also, am I to understand that the data should only be populated if the id (child or parent) appears in arr1, but ignored if it only appears in arr2? If so, then the condition should be: if (is_array($arr1[$key]['children']))

Comment: there will never be a case where the ID appears in only one array, however if it's only in the data array then it should be ignored I guess. I did see the edit but it doesn't work as I said. I added more info to the OP with working examples and output if you'd like to test it out, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I had a moment and wrote something on my localhost that appears to work. See the top of the edited answer

Comment: thank you for the answer, flattening the 2nd array is the same solution @Thijn came up with which works.  I wish I could upvote you for your help but I don't have enough rep to do so. Thanks for the help regardless.

Comment: No worries- hadn't noticed he'd beat me to it